# Can I pass a parameter set via exec()'s name space?

Tags: python, exec

I'm trying to create a parameter sweep pattern, using python's exec() function and passing it a particular parameter set via a namespace.  My application is a scipy.integrate.odeint() model with a bunch of parameters, but my attempt to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) test replaces this with a simple parameter reporting function.  Similarly, I've not included the full set of parameters and ranges because the examples make these obvious.

```
def rptParam():
    print 'rptParam: v=%e b0=%e drme=%e de=%e TGrate=%f IPer=%d' % (v,b0,drme,de,TGrate,IPer)

def tstIterExec(argList, argRange, seed):

    seedTup = tuple([seed[k] for k in argList])
    print 'tstIterExec: seed', seedTup
    seed['rptParam'] = rptParam
    tstCode = compile("rptParam()", '<string>','exec')

    for param,v in seed.items():
        if param not in argList:
            print 'tstIterExec: skipping param', param
            continue

        print 'tstIterExec: varying', param
        ai = argList.index(param)
        spos = argRange[ai].index(v)
        #  higher values of param
        for vi in range(spos+1,len(argRange[ai])): 
            currContext = seed.copy()
            currContext[param] = argRange[ai][vi]               # perturb just this value of seed
            seedTup = tuple([currContext[k] for k in argList])  # a hashable version of the seed
            print 'tstIterExec: perturb', param, seedTup
            exec tstCode in globals(), currContext


tstArgList = ['v','b0']
tstArgRange = [v_Range, b0_Range]

TstSeed = {'v':3e-2, 'b0':2e-11, 'drme':5e-2, 'de':0.8 ,'TGrate': 0.2, 'IPer':10}
tstIterExec(tstArgList, tstArgRange, TstSeed)
```

Running this code produces this output:

```
tstIterExec: seed (0.03, 2e-11)
tstIterExec: skipping param drme
tstIterExec: skipping param TGrate
tstIterExec: skipping param de
tstIterExec: varying b0
tstIterExec: perturb b0 (0.03, 4e-11)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: perturb b0 (0.03, 8e-11)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: perturb b0 (0.03, 1e-10)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: perturb b0 (0.03, 1e-09)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: varying v
tstIterExec: perturb v (0.032, 2e-11)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: perturb v (0.048, 2e-11)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: perturb v (0.064, 2e-11)
rptParam: v=3.200000e-02 b0=2.000000e-11 drme=5.000000e-02 de=8.500000e-01 TGrate=0.200000 IPer=10
tstIterExec: skipping param rptParam
tstIterExec: skipping param IPer
```

Obviously, the currContext is changing within tstIterExec() but rptParam() insists on using global bindings?  I've also tried sending in the currContext as the first, globals namespace; same behavior.

i must be misunderstanding python's namespace/closure notions?  is exec() even the appropriate technology for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `globals` and `locals` passed to an `exec` statement only affect the immediate code object being executed by `exec`; they don't affect any functions that code object invokes.  The globals as seen by `rptParam` are still the module globals, so it's printing values of `v` etc. that are in your module.

As far as I can tell the best bet would just be to accept the parameters as arguments:

```
def rptParam(v, ...):
    ...

...

            print 'tstIterExec: perturb', param, seedTup
            rptParam(**currContext)
```

Comment: thanks ecatmur, and i agree passing as explicit parameters could be a work around.  but in fact function calls functions ... that finally call the  scipy.integrate.odeint() function.  i think of closures as a good way to handle this, and i thought exec namespaces did that?

Comment: @rikb `exec` doesn't affect the closure of a function defined elsewhere in your code.  You can always pass the parameters through and only unpack them where you need them.

Comment: i've been hoping for second opinions from other Pythonics; missing Lisp features makes me feel old(:  @ecatmur, i appreciate your answer, even if i don't like it.

Comment: @rikb ah, you're looking for dynamic scoping.  Python is lexically scoped, barring hacks, so the "global" scope of a function is always the namespace of the module it is defined in.

Comment: maybe what i'm looking for are python's dynamic scoping hacks?  does any of this change in Python3?

Comment: and now i'm wondering if argument passing can even work:  the call into which i need to import my param values is the `model` passed in `integrate.odeint(model, initCond, t)`.  but passing params to `integrate.ideint()` won't help?!

Comment: @rikb `integrate.odeint` takes an `args` parameter with extra arguments, or you can use a partial, lambda or function closure.

Comment: i wound up doing a version of parameter passing, but it wound up being very ugly to my eyes.  i'll convert my gross solution into a new SSCCE test and try to ask better next time.   @ecatmur, i'm going to call your responses an answer, to thank you in +reputation for your help.